# $n^{\frac{1}{2}}e_{n}$ doesn't weakly converge to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $\{e_{n}\}$ be an orthonormal basis for a Hilbert space H.

Show that $n^{\frac{1}{2}}e_{n}$ does not converge weakly to $0$

For contradiction, $n^{\frac{1}{2}}e_{n}$ converges weakly to $0$, so we have that
$$\langle  n^{\frac{1}{2}}e_{n},h\rangle \to \langle0,h\rangle=0 $$ for all $h\in H$, what would be the next? what can I say of this? another idea ?

Comment: Tip: use \langle and \rangle for inner product braces

Comment: a weakly convergent sequence on a Hilbert space (more generally on any normed space) is necessarly Norm bounded.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Let $a_n=\frac 1 {\sqrt n}$ when $n$ is of the type $m^{4}$ and $0$ for all other $n$. Take $h =\sum a_ne_n$.

Comment: @geetha290km  hi!, i had a question. what are you talking when you say type $m^4$?

Comment: It means $n$ is the 4th power of some positive integer: $n \in \{1,2^{4},3^{4},...\}$. @LMOTRU